# Davenport, the usage of mean value theorem

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions

In Davenport, Multiplicative Number Theory, page 6, the author asserts that:

"Let $\omega$ be a complex character. Suppose $L_{\omega}(1)=0$, then it would imply that $L_{\omega}(s)=L_{\omega}(s)-L_{\omega}(1) = (s-1)L'_{\omega}(s_1)$, where $s>1$ and $1<s_1<s$."

I do not think that we are allowed to use MVT here, as $L_{\omega}(s)$ does not have to be a real-valued function for every $s>1$. (or this is the piece I could not figure out.)

I looked at the Euler product expression for $\displaystyle L_{\omega}(s) = \prod_{p\neq q}\left(1-\frac{\omega^{v(p)}}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$, but it does not really seem to be real for every $s>1$.

I tried a complex character $\mathrm{mod}7$ with the character $\omega$ respectively taking the values $1,e^{2\pi i/3},e^{\pi i/3},e^{-\pi i/3},e^{-2\pi i/3},-1$ and I obtained with the help of wolfram alpha that $L_{\omega}(2) \approx 0.902 - 0.242i$. Since Dirichlet $L$ functions are absolutely convergent for $s>1$, I separated the modulo classes and add them up later on. Is my procedure faulty?

I also know that $\displaystyle\prod_{\omega} L_{\omega}(s) \geq 1$ for $s>1$, but from this I cannot deduce anything. Is there some kind of another tool the author is using here or is the $L$ function real for $s>1$ for some mysterious reason I am not aware of? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\overline {L_{\omega}(s)}=L_{\bar \omega}(s)$ for real $s$ so indeed $L_{\omega}(s)$ is not real in general for real $s$, but $L_{\omega}$ is an analytic function on a neighborhood of $1$ so the fact that if $L_{\omega}(s)=0$ then $|L_{\omega}(s)| \le C|s-1|$ for nearby $s$ follows from the taylor series for example

Comment: I can now see that $L_{\omega}(s) = L_{\omega}(1)+L'_{\omega}(1)(s-1)+\ldots$. But why we have that $L'_{\omega}(1)(s-1)+\ldots = L'_{\omega}(s_1)$ for some $s_1$ in between $1$ and $s$. As far as I remember, in real case, to show that we use mean value theorem.

Comment: @mertunsal It is possible that Davenport used an erroneous argument to obtain that bound for $L_\omega(s)$. However, the bound is not incorrect, and Taylor series expansion can be used to deduce it.

Comment: It is also possible to obtain the bound by considering real and imaginary parts of the Dirichlet series, they give two different constants $s_1,s_2$ and do not validate the argument given in Davenport though. I will assume that it is a small mistake as it can be corrected pretty easily. Thanks a lot for your help!